# R refill NA values within group using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I've the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- data_frame(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                     3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L), 
              wish1 = c(4L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
                        NA, -1L, 8L, NA, 1L, -1L, NA, 4L, 
                        NA, NA, -1L), 
              wish2 = c(1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
                        NA, -1L, 1L, NA, 2L, -1L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L), 
              participate = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
                              NA, 1L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA))
```

I want to replace within each group the `NA`s of variable `participate` with the values which are available within the same group. If there are no values within the group, then the `NA` can stay.

I need something like:

```
df <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(participate = (participate, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work without a function like `sum` or anything.

Comment: `participate` is only 19 long, so the code doesn't run as-is. That said, something like `dat %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(participate = first(na.omit(participate)))` should work.

Comment: @alistaire I tried your code and got this error `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Unsupported vector type language`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @alistaire I found that if using `arrange` to sort the data frame by `id` and `participate` first, there is no need to use `na.omit`. Here is the code: `dat %>% arrange(id, participate) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(participate = first(participate))`. This is probably by far the most concise solution.

Comment: or base: `dat$participate <- ave(dat$participate, dat$id, FUN = function(x){sort(x)[1]})` or data.table: `setDT(dat)[, participate := sort(participate)[1], by = id][]`

Comment: I corrected the code now. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably more concise or elegant ways, but I would like to share some thoughts.

## Solution 1: Use the fill function from tidyr

```
library(tidyr)

# the fill function can fill the NA based on the previous entry
dat2 <- dat %>%
  arrange(id, participate) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(participate)
```

## Solution 2: Determine the fill values, then use left_join

```
# dat_temp is a summary data frame showing the fill values
dat_temp <- dat %>%
  arrange(id, participate) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(id, participate)

# Join dat_temp to dat2
dat2 <- dat %>%
  left_join(dat_temp, by = "id") %>%
  select(-participate.x) %>%
  rename(participate = participate.y)
```

## Solution 3: Sort the data frame then fill the NA based on the first value

This solution is based on the comment from alistaire

```
dat2 <- dat %>% 
  arrange(id, participate) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(participate = first(participate))
```

Comment: Thanks for summarizing the comments into the three different solutions. While preferring the first one, I still learn a lot from the other two!